# Assigning multiple Retrofit response values to an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, retrofit

I'm struggling to implement a solution to retrieve multiple values from my api response ( https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=13060 ) and assign specific values to an array. Specifically values, strIngredient1, strIngredient2, strIngredient3 etc...

At present i created a POJO cocktail class as follows:

```
public class Cocktail implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("idDrink")
@Expose
private String idDrink;
@SerializedName("strDrink")
@Expose
private String strDrink;
@SerializedName("strVideo")
@Expose
private Object strVideo;
@SerializedName("strCategory")
@Expose
private String strCategory;
@SerializedName("strIBA")
@Expose
private Object strIBA;
@SerializedName("strAlcoholic")
@Expose
private String strAlcoholic;
@SerializedName("strGlass")
@Expose
private String strGlass;
@SerializedName("strInstructions")
@Expose
private String strInstructions;
@SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
@Expose
private String strDrinkThumb;
@SerializedName("strIngredient1")
@Expose
private String strIngredient1;
@SerializedName("strIngredient2")
@Expose
private String strIngredient2;
@SerializedName("strIngredient3")
@Expose
private String strIngredient3;
@SerializedName("strIngredient4")
@Expose
private String strIngredient4;
@SerializedName("strIngredient5")
@Expose
private String strIngredient5;
@SerializedName("strIngredient6")
@Expose
private String strIngredient6;
@SerializedName("strIngredient7")
@Expose
private String strIngredient7;
@SerializedName("strIngredient8")
@Expose
private String strIngredient8;
@SerializedName("strIngredient9")
@Expose
private String strIngredient9;
@SerializedName("strIngredient10")
@Expose
private String strIngredient10;
@SerializedName("strIngredient11")
@Expose
private String strIngredient11;
@SerializedName("strIngredient12")
@Expose
private String strIngredient12;
@SerializedName("strIngredient13")
@Expose
private String strIngredient13;
@SerializedName("strIngredient14")
@Expose
private String strIngredient14;
@SerializedName("strIngredient15")
@Expose
private String strIngredient15;
@SerializedName("strMeasure1")
@Expose
private String strMeasure1;
@SerializedName("strMeasure2")
@Expose
private String strMeasure2;
@SerializedName("strMeasure3")
@Expose
private String strMeasure3;
@SerializedName("strMeasure4")
@Expose
private String strMeasure4;
@SerializedName("strMeasure5")
@Expose
private String strMeasure5;
@SerializedName("strMeasure6")
@Expose
private String strMeasure6;
@SerializedName("strMeasure7")
@Expose
private String strMeasure7;
@SerializedName("strMeasure8")
@Expose
private String strMeasure8;
@SerializedName("strMeasure9")
@Expose
private String strMeasure9;
@SerializedName("strMeasure10")
@Expose
private String strMeasure10;
@SerializedName("strMeasure11")
@Expose
private String strMeasure11;
@SerializedName("strMeasure12")
@Expose
private String strMeasure12;
@SerializedName("strMeasure13")
@Expose
private String strMeasure13;
@SerializedName("strMeasure14")
@Expose
private String strMeasure14;
@SerializedName("strMeasure15")
@Expose
private String strMeasure15;
@SerializedName("dateModified")
@Expose
private String dateModified;

public String getIdDrink() {
    return idDrink;
}

public void setIdDrink(String idDrink) {
    this.idDrink = idDrink;
}

public String getStrDrink() {
    return strDrink;
}

public void setStrDrink(String strDrink) {
    this.strDrink = strDrink;
}

public Object getStrVideo() {
    return strVideo;
}

public void setStrVideo(Object strVideo) {
    this.strVideo = strVideo;
}

public String getStrCategory() {
    return strCategory;
}

public void setStrCategory(String strCategory) {
    this.strCategory = strCategory;
}

public Object getStrIBA() {
    return strIBA;
}

public void setStrIBA(Object strIBA) {
    this.strIBA = strIBA;
}

public String getStrAlcoholic() {
    return strAlcoholic;
}

public void setStrAlcoholic(String strAlcoholic) {
    this.strAlcoholic = strAlcoholic;
}

public String getStrGlass() {
    return strGlass;
}

public void setStrGlass(String strGlass) {
    this.strGlass = strGlass;
}

public String getStrInstructions() {
    return strInstructions;
}

public void setStrInstructions(String strInstructions) {
    this.strInstructions = strInstructions;
}

public String getStrDrinkThumb() {
    return strDrinkThumb;
}

public void setStrDrinkThumb(String strDrinkThumb) {
    this.strDrinkThumb = strDrinkThumb;
}

public String getStrIngredient1() {
    return strIngredient1;
}

public void setStrIngredient1(String strIngredient1) {
    this.strIngredient1 = strIngredient1;
}

public String getStrIngredient2() {
    return strIngredient2;
}

public void setStrIngredient2(String strIngredient2) {
    this.strIngredient2 = strIngredient2;
}

public String getStrIngredient3() {
    return strIngredient3;
}

public void setStrIngredient3(String strIngredient3) {
    this.strIngredient3 = strIngredient3;
}

public String getStrIngredient4() {
    return strIngredient4;
}

public void setStrIngredient4(String strIngredient4) {
    this.strIngredient4 = strIngredient4;
}

public String getStrIngredient5() {
    return strIngredient5;
}

public void setStrIngredient5(String strIngredient5) {
    this.strIngredient5 = strIngredient5;
}

public String getStrIngredient6() {
    return strIngredient6;
}

public void setStrIngredient6(String strIngredient6) {
    this.strIngredient6 = strIngredient6;
}

public String getStrIngredient7() {
    return strIngredient7;
}

public void setStrIngredient7(String strIngredient7) {
    this.strIngredient7 = strIngredient7;
}

public String getStrIngredient8() {
    return strIngredient8;
}

public void setStrIngredient8(String strIngredient8) {
    this.strIngredient8 = strIngredient8;
}

public String getStrIngredient9() {
    return strIngredient9;
}

public void setStrIngredient9(String strIngredient9) {
    this.strIngredient9 = strIngredient9;
}

public String getStrIngredient10() {
    return strIngredient10;
}

public void setStrIngredient10(String strIngredient10) {
    this.strIngredient10 = strIngredient10;
}

public String getStrIngredient11() {
    return strIngredient11;
}

public void setStrIngredient11(String strIngredient11) {
    this.strIngredient11 = strIngredient11;
}

public String getStrIngredient12() {
    return strIngredient12;
}

public void setStrIngredient12(String strIngredient12) {
    this.strIngredient12 = strIngredient12;
}

public String getStrIngredient13() {
    return strIngredient13;
}

public void setStrIngredient13(String strIngredient13) {
    this.strIngredient13 = strIngredient13;
}

public String getStrIngredient14() {
    return strIngredient14;
}

public void setStrIngredient14(String strIngredient14) {
    this.strIngredient14 = strIngredient14;
}

public String getStrIngredient15() {
    return strIngredient15;
}

public void setStrIngredient15(String strIngredient15) {
    this.strIngredient15 = strIngredient15;
}

public String getStrMeasure1() {
    return strMeasure1;
}

public void setStrMeasure1(String strMeasure1) {
    this.strMeasure1 = strMeasure1;
}

public String getStrMeasure2() {
    return strMeasure2;
}

public void setStrMeasure2(String strMeasure2) {
    this.strMeasure2 = strMeasure2;
}

public String getStrMeasure3() {
    return strMeasure3;
}

public void setStrMeasure3(String strMeasure3) {
    this.strMeasure3 = strMeasure3;
}

public String getStrMeasure4() {
    return strMeasure4;
}

public void setStrMeasure4(String strMeasure4) {
    this.strMeasure4 = strMeasure4;
}

public String getStrMeasure5() {
    return strMeasure5;
}

public void setStrMeasure5(String strMeasure5) {
    this.strMeasure5 = strMeasure5;
}

public String getStrMeasure6() {
    return strMeasure6;
}

public void setStrMeasure6(String strMeasure6) {
    this.strMeasure6 = strMeasure6;
}

public String getStrMeasure7() {
    return strMeasure7;
}

public void setStrMeasure7(String strMeasure7) {
    this.strMeasure7 = strMeasure7;
}

public String getStrMeasure8() {
    return strMeasure8;
}

public void setStrMeasure8(String strMeasure8) {
    this.strMeasure8 = strMeasure8;
}

public String getStrMeasure9() {
    return strMeasure9;
}

public void setStrMeasure9(String strMeasure9) {
    this.strMeasure9 = strMeasure9;
}

public String getStrMeasure10() {
    return strMeasure10;
}

public void setStrMeasure10(String strMeasure10) {
    this.strMeasure10 = strMeasure10;
}

public String getStrMeasure11() {
    return strMeasure11;
}

public void setStrMeasure11(String strMeasure11) {
    this.strMeasure11 = strMeasure11;
}

public String getStrMeasure12() {
    return strMeasure12;
}

public void setStrMeasure12(String strMeasure12) {
    this.strMeasure12 = strMeasure12;
}

public String getStrMeasure13() {
    return strMeasure13;
}

public void setStrMeasure13(String strMeasure13) {
    this.strMeasure13 = strMeasure13;
}

public String getStrMeasure14() {
    return strMeasure14;
}

public void setStrMeasure14(String strMeasure14) {
    this.strMeasure14 = strMeasure14;
}

public String getStrMeasure15() {
    return strMeasure15;
}

public void setStrMeasure15(String strMeasure15) {
    this.strMeasure15 = strMeasure15;
}

public String getDateModified() {
    return dateModified;
}

public void setDateModified(String dateModified) {
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
}
```

And my API call is as follows:

```
@Override
protected Cocktail doInBackground(Cocktail... cocktails) {

    Call<Cocktails> call = mApiService.getCocktail(id);
    try {
        Response<Cocktails> response = call.execute();
        this.cocktails = response.body();
        this.cocktail = this.cocktails.getCocktail().get(0);

        Log.i(TAG, "Success: " + response.body().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cocktail;
}
```

I know enough to realise that a large number of variables, ingredients and measures (many of which are empty) is the wrong approach but i'm struggling to find a solution with retrofit to create an array of these values. I've not found any way to assign multiple SerializedNames to a single array variable?

The option that jumps out at me is looping through the response pulling out the key values in onSuccess but this seems to go against the simplicity of using retrofit?

Comment: Why do you think that this is the wrong approach? The retrofit object should match your response object.

Comment: It doesnt seem logical to me to have 15 ingredient variables and 15 measure variables. These should be incorporated into two arrays surely?

Comment: The problem is with your server response. The server should be responding with an array. So your response object could match it without having to write a lot of code to it.